# Mongodb sphere2d query

Tags: mongodb

Hi i have an collection which contains this object

```
{
   "_id":"53b0807ca004f2ad5f0c9839",
   "id":"3427734",
   "version":"4",
   "timestamp":"2012-08-04T12:06:46Z",
   "changeset":"12608469",
   "uid":"604523",
   "user":"673a",
   "fenced":"yes",
   "landuse":"cemetery",
   "name":"Friedhof St. Peter (Alter Friedhof)",
   "poly":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               8.6763586,
               49.5531628
            ],
            [
               8.6765129,
               49.553132
            ],
            [
               8.6763608,
               49.5528116
            ],
            [
               8.6767028,
               49.5527433
            ],
            [
               8.6765809,
               49.5524866
            ],
            [
               8.6770135,
               49.5524431
            ],
            [
               8.6784924,
               49.5520942
            ],
            [
               8.6788149,
               49.5521769
            ],
            [
               8.6789908,
               49.5524369
            ],
            [
               8.6793862,
               49.5525109
            ],
            [
               8.6786997,
               49.5530378
            ],
            [
               8.6779331,
               49.5531445
            ],
            [
               8.6769458,
               49.5532933
            ],
            [
               8.6766567,
               49.5533521
            ],
            [
               8.6764405,
               49.5533353
            ],
            [
               8.6763586,
               49.5531628
            ]
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

now i'm makeing a query

```
{
   "poly":{
      $geoIntersects:{
         $geometry:{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -180.0,
                     90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     180.0,
                     90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     180.0,
                     -90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     -180.0,
                     -90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     -180.0,
                     90.0
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but it does not return the object.. it returns nothing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GeoJson object that you passed is not acceptable. I changed the query parameter a little bit and it now works. As you have already understood now that the GeoJson object should fit within one hemisphere. If you need some demonstration of the `$geoIntersect` functionality of MongoDB, you can run the following query and see that it gives your polygon in the results:

```
db.Test.find({
   "poly":{
      '$geoIntersects':{
         '$geometry':{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        8.6763586,
        49.5531628
      ],
      [
        8.6788149,
        49.5521769
      ],
      [
        8.6786997,
        49.5530378
      ],
      [
        8.6763586,
        49.5531628
      ],
      [
        8.6763586,
        49.5531628
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: i already have this index, but doesn't change anything, does it work for you?

Comment: do you know which hemispheres are meant? north-south or east-west?

Comment: @wutzebaer : It is important to note that the queries supported by MongoDB are not geographical queries, but geometry based queries. Therefore, I think, it isn't about N-S or E-W hemisphere. All that matters is if it extends beyond one half of the sphere.

Comment: means the startpoint is not important, but my query polygon's width must not exceed the width of 180 degrees?

Comment: i have to add that it seems that the width must be < 180, when i'ts exactly 180 the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my query won't work, i found this in the docs:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/

```
Note

Any geometry specified with GeoJSON to $geoIntersects queries, must fit within a single hemisphere. MongoDB interprets geometries larger than half of the sphere as queries for the smaller of the complementary geometries.
```

i can only query fopr the right hmisphere

```
{
   "poly":{
      $geoIntersects:{
         $geometry:{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     1.0,
                     90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     180.0,
                     90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     180.0,
                     -90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     1.0,
                     -90.0
                  ],
                  [
                     1.0,
                     90.0
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```